# Reqular expression to separate equalities

Tags: python, regex, equality

Does anyone have some good resources on learning more advanced regular expressions

I keep having problems where I want to make sure something is not enclosed in quotation marks

i.e. I am trying to make an expression that will match lines in a python file containing an equality, i.e.

```
a = 4
```

which is easy enough, but I am having trouble devising an expression that would be able to separate out multiple terms or ones wrapped in quotes like these:

```
a, b = b, a
a,b = "You say yes, ", "i say no"
```

Comment: What about single-quote strings, triple quoted strings, escaped quotes, escaped backslashes, raw strings, code comments, etc. How should you regular expression handle those?

Comment: You say stop, but I say go, go, go!!!  (sorry, could not resist)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A think that you have to tokenize the expression for correct evaluation but you can detect the pattern using the following regex

```
r'\s+(\w+)(\s*,\s*\w+)*\s*=\s*(.*?)(\s*,\s*.*?)*'
```

If group(2) and group(4) are not empty you have to tokenize the expression

Note that if you have

a,b = f(b,a), g(a,b)

It is hard to analyze

Comment: at least this solves, one part of my problem (i didn't know you could collect multiple groups this way), so il mark you up as the solution, i have solved the other part in a hackish round about way so that will do,

Answer (score 4):

Parsing code with regular expressions is generally not a good idea, as the grammar of a programming language is not a regular language. I'm not much of a python programmer, but I think you would be a lot better off parsing python code with python modules such as [this one](http://docs.python.org/library/parser.html) or [this one](http://docs.python.org/library/ast.html)

Comment: to me these seem like overkill and compliction for what im doing, my project is for a little script that desk checks python programs, (y12 software)

Comment: It might seem that way, but the Voice of Experience will tell you it isn't.

Comment: for a full blown project i agree that using a parser would make more sense, for this though my program just runs over the code and ads functions that wrap around statements and write to a log file

Answer (score 1):

Python has an excellent [Language Reference](http://docs.python.org/reference/index.html) that also includes [descriptions of the lexical analysis and syntax](http://docs.python.org/reference/introduction.html#notation).

In your case both statements are [assignments](http://docs.python.org/reference/simple_stmts.html#assignment-statements) with a [list of targets](http://docs.python.org/reference/simple_stmts.html#grammar-token-target_list) on the left hand side and and a [list of expressions](http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#grammar-token-expression_list) on the right hand side.

But since parts of that grammar part are context-free and not regular, you can’t use regular expressions (unless they support some kind of recursive patterns). So better use a proper parser [as Jonas H suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4666527/reqular-expression-to-seperate-equalitys/4666575#4666575).